# Want counter to start counting only when in viewport

Tags: counter

I have a counter that is working perfectly fine, but it starts counting when the page is loaded - meaning that often when the user scrolls down, the counter has already stoped and therefore the effect is lost.

I've tried multiple suggestions found here on Stack Overflow, but none worked for my specific case.

Here's my code:

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },
  {
    duration: 9000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }
  });
});
```

Any tips I could incorporate into my code to ensure the counter starts counting only in viewport?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to achive is using IntersectionObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API to active your countdown when in viewport.

First, create an observer that will trigger when in view, and then start countdown.

```
const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px', //this determines when observer will trigger
    threshold: 0
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting) {
          observer.unobserve(entry.target)
          activateCountdown(entry.target) //call you function that will activate the counter
        }
    })
}, options);
```

Now, apply this observer to all counter that exists

```
$('.counter').each((index, element) => {
  observer.observe(element)
})

function activateCountdown(countdown) {
 //here you activate your counter
}
```

Comment: Hi Luis! Thank you so much for trying to help out. Did you mean pasting all the code you sent and replacing the line "//here you activate your counter" by the code I sent on my original question?

Comment: This can work, but I strongly recommend understand how IntersectionObserver works.